# Centering svg shapes inside one another

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I just faced a situation where I want to place SVG shapes in center of one another with different scales.
for example placing a rectangle or triangle or any other shapes in the center of a circle.

I came across some solutions for this purpose but just working for some shapes which has x and y attributes like rectangle.
as an example I place a rectangle in center of a circle like this: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0uf8pqmt/2/)

```
var circle =document.getElementById('c1');
var rect = document.getElementById('r1');
var group = document.getElementById('g1');
var BBox = rect.getBBox();

rect.setAttribute('x',-(BBox.width/2));
rect.setAttribute('y',-(BBox.height/2));

rect.setAttribute('transform','scale(2)');
circle.setAttribute('transform','scale(1)');
group.setAttribute('transform','translate(200,150)');
```

but as you see It sets the rectangle x and y attributes. but if I have a triangle for example, it dose not have any x or y attribute because it is a path.
I think if it was a solution to set the bounding box x and y attributes of the triangle or any other shape it would work like what I do in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pqvpzasn/1/)

```
BBox.setAttribute('x',-(BBox.width/2));
BBox.setAttribute('y',-(BBox.height/2));
```

but it dose not work as expected because I might made some mistake in setting BBox attribute.

now my question is that is there any solution to set the bounding box attributes or is there any other better solution to place a shape in center of another one?

thanks.

Comment: Hum, I have no time to test it today but your code seems good. Except I think it's BBox.setAttribute('y',-(BBox.height/2)); and not width, isn't it ?

Comment: And I think BBox doesn't have setAttribute method. it have to be checked ..

Comment: Yes right and I just mentioned that it dose not work right and I want to know is there any way to set BBox attributes or not or is this a right solution or not.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't take the time to read well. :/ I think you will need to use the viewport of the object (set the object in his viewport and move the viewport).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounding box (as returned by `getBBox()` etc) is a read-only property.  You cannot adjust the position of an element by changing the bbox values.

If you want to reposition a `<path>` element, you have to either: (a) change the coordinates in the `d` attribute, or (b) use the `transform` attribute.

Comment: Thank you. that is right and I can place the rectangle in center of circle. but I don't know why it dos not work for every path shapes. I wonder if there is a better way to center a shape in another one ?

Comment: I have tried with a triangle like this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/zobj7otj/) but it is not in the center of the circle. I know i have done something wrong but do not know where?

Comment: Your code is working correctly.  If you look above and below the triangle, the distance to the edge of the circle is the same.  The problem here is that the centroid of the triangle is not the same as the average of its widths/heights.  In other words, half way up the triangle is not its geometric centre.  In a triangle the centroid is actually at 1/3 the height.  So instead of moving it up 1/2, move it up 2/3.  http://jsfiddle.net/zobj7otj/1/

Comment: Thank you very much your solution is very nice my problem is solved.